# Making Symfony2 unit tests more DRY by extending WebTestCase

Tags: unit-testing, symfony

A lot of my tests have a lot of the same `setUp()`/`tearDown()` stuff going on. It seems dumb to copy and paste the same code into every single one of my unit tests. I think I want to create a new test class that extends `WebTestCase` that my other tests can extend.

My problem is that I don't really know how. First of all, where's the most appropriate place to put this new class? I tried making one just inside my `Tests` folder, but then none of my tests could actually find the class. Maybe I just don't understand namespaces.

Has anyone extended `WebTestCase` before in the way I'm talking about? If so, how did you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't done this, but I'd probably just do it like so

**src/Your/Bundle/Test/WebTestCase.php**

```
<?php

namespace Your\Bundle\Test

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase as WTC;

class WebTestCase extends WTC
{
  // Your implementation of WebTestCase
}
```

Comment: Using your method I'm getting an error: Class 'Your\Bundle\Test\WebTestCase' not found in test. How could I force symfony to load my class?

Answer (score 2):

In my tests I usually extend the WebTestCase the way Peter proposed it. Additionally I use require_once to make the AppKernel available in my WebTestCase:

```
<?php

namespace My\Bundle\Tests;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase as BaseWebTestCase;

require_once(__DIR__ . "/../../../../app/AppKernel.php");

class WebTestCase extends BaseWebTestCase
{
  protected $_application;

  protected $_container;

  public function setUp()
  {
    $kernel = new \AppKernel("test", true);
    $kernel->boot();
    $this->_application = new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application($kernel);
    $this->_application->setAutoExit(false);

...
```

My tests then look like this:

```
<?php

namespace My\Bundle\Tests\Controller;

use My\Bundle\Tests\WebTestCase;

class DefaultControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to extend WebTestCase to include AppKernel. You can use the following approach

```
    $client = static::createClient();
    self::$application = new Application($client->getKernel());
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is really old but it ranks quite highly on Google, so I thought I'd add my solution.

I extended `WebTestCase` with a default `setUp` method and a `logIn` method so I could more easily run authenticated tests.

It seems you can't add standard classes to the `tests` directory because the unit tests won't find them. I'm not sure why. My solution was to add a directory `src/_TestHelpers` and put my helper classes in there.

So I have:

```
# src/_TestHelpers/ExtendedWTC.php
namespace _TestHelpers;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class ExtendedWTC extends WebTestCase
{
    # Do your cool extending here
}
```

and

```
# tests/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php
namespace Tests\AppBundle;

use _TestHelpers\ExtendedWTC

class DefaultControllerTest extends ExtendedWTC
{
    # Your tests here, using your cool extensions.
}
```

Note: I'm using the `Symfony 3` directory structure, hence why my tests are in `tests/` and not `src/AppBundle/Tests/`.

I hope this helps someone...